# Why do the new paragraphs I add with jQuery do nothing on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some paragraphs in my html as an example, and when I click on it, the JQuery click activates correctly and executes de function. However, I have a button that adds new paragraphs to de body but the new ones do nothing on click and I don't know why:

My html body

```
        <h1> Test </h1>
        <input type="text" id="newP" value="New paragraph">
        <button id="add"> Add </button>
        <p> Paragraph 1 </p>
        <p> Paragraph 2 </p>
```

My js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("p").click(function(){
    console.log("Hello");
    this.remove();
});
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#add").after("<p> " + $("#newP").val() + "</p>");
});
});
```

The 2 example paragraphs delete correctly and shows "Hello" but de new ones don't. I want to do something more complicated than just deleting them so I need to know why the function isn't working for them. (I must use JQuery)

Comment: Not exactly, because it must be with jquery. Its for a class exercise

Comment: There is a jquery version in the accepted answer. You can replace `$(document)` with the parent element of where your dynamic elements appear if you want, or leave as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you add new click listeners before adding new elements.
You can use the three-argument form of the click handler it will apply also to new elements added.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#add', function(){
    $(this).after("<p> " + $("#newP").val() + "</p>");
});
```

Another issue might be that you have multiple elements with the same id. You should give them css classes like `add` and then select for `.add`.